# (bash) What is the least redundant way to systematically apply changes to an array of variables?

Tags: bash

My goal is to check a list of file paths if they end in "/" and remove it if that is the case.

Ideally I would like to change the original FILEPATH variables to reflect this change, and I'd like this to work for a long list without unnecessary redundancy. I tried doing it as a loop, but the changes didn't alter the original variables, it just changed the iterating "EACH_PATH" variable. Can anyone think of a better way to do this?

Here is my code:

```
FILEPATH1="filepath1/file1"
FILEPATH2="filepath2/file2/"
PATH_ARRAY=(${FILEPATH1} ${FILEPATH2})
echo ${PATH_ARRAY[@]}
for EACH_PATH in ${PATH_ARRAY[@]}
    do
        if [ "${EACH_PATH:$((${#EACH_PATH}-1)):${#EACH_PATH}}"=="/" ]
            then EACH_PATH=${EACH_PATH:0:$((${#EACH_PATH}-1))}
        fi
done
```

edit: I'm happy to do this in a totally different way and scrap the code above, I just want to know the most elegant way to do this.

Comment: Quote your variables, also try https://shellcheck.net for validating your script.

Comment: Hi, after correcting the syntax errors as Jetchisel indicated, tell us: Is there any good reason for having those `FILEPATH` variables if you have the very same information inside the array?

Comment: Thank you for the syntax advice.  (It still doesn't change the FILEPATH variables.) This is a simple test case for a larger script I am making and the filepath variables are coming from user input.

Comment: `PATH_ARRAY` is not an array of variables; it is an array of strings (which happen to come from variables, but are not in any way tied to those variables). Changing the array won't affect the variables, nor will changing the variables affect the array.

Comment: Also with a high number of filepath variables I want to make it as clear as possible (the filepath variables will have more detailed names)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely clear on the actual goal here, but depending on the situation I can see several possible solutions. The best (if it'll work in the situation) is to dispense with the individual variables, and just use array entries. For example, you could use:

```
declare -a filepath
filepath[1]="filepath1/file1"
filepath[2]="filepath2/file2/"
for index in "${!filepath[@]}"; do
    if [[ "${filepath[index]}" = *?/ ]]; then
        filepath[index]="${filepath[index]%/}"
    fi
done
```

...and then use `"${filepath[x]}"` instead of `"$FILEPATHx"` throughout. Some notes:

- I've used lowercase names. It's generally best to avoid all-caps names, since there are a lot of them with special functions, and accidentally using one of those names can cause trouble.
- `"${!filepath[@]}"` gets a list of the *indexes* of the array (in this case, "1" "2") rather than their values; this is necessary so we can *set* the entries rather than just look at them.
- I changed the logic of the slash-trimming test -- it uses `[[ = ]]` to do pattern matching, to see if the entry ends with "/" and has at least one character before that (i.e. it isn't *just* "/", 'cause you don't want to trim that). Then it uses in the expansion `%/` to just trim "/" from the end of the value.

If a numerically-indexed array won't work (and you have at least bash version 4), how about a string-indexed ("associative") array? It's very similar, but use `declare -A` and use `$` on variables in the index (and generally quote them). Something like this:

```
declare -A filepath
filepath["foo"]="filepath1/file1"
filepath["bar"]="filepath2/file2/"
for index in "${!filepath[@]}"; do
    if [[ "${filepath["$index"]}" = *?/ ]]; then
        filepath["$index"]="${filepath["$index"]%/}"
    fi
done
```

If you really need separate variables instead of array entries, you might be able to use an array of variable *names*, and indirect variable references. how this works [varies quite a bit between different shells](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/006#Indirection), and can easily be unsafe depending on what's in your data (in this case, specifically what's in `path_array`). Here's a way to do it in bash:

```
filepath1="filepath1/file1"
filepath2="filepath2/file2/"
path_array=(filepath1 filepath2)
for varname in "${path_array[@]}"; do
    if [[ "${!varname}" = *?/ ]]; then
        declare "$varname=${!varname%/}"
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Using sed

```
PATH_ARRAY=($(echo ${PATH_ARRAY[@]} | sed 's#\/ ##g;s#/$##g'))
```

Demo:

```
$FILEPATH1="filepath1/file1"
$FILEPATH2="filepath2/file2/"
$PATH_ARRAY=(${FILEPATH1} ${FILEPATH2})
$echo ${PATH_ARRAY[@]}
filepath1/file1 filepath2/file2/
$PATH_ARRAY=($(echo ${PATH_ARRAY[@]} | sed 's#\/ ##g;s#/$##g'))
$echo ${PATH_ARRAY[@]}
filepath1/file1 filepath2/file2
$
```